# Editing the DOM with Javascript

Tags: blazor

I'm using MathQuill to render latex on my page but this is conflicting with the render tree.

Javascript being called by blazor:

```
RenderQuizInterface: function () {

    MQ.StaticMath(document.getElementById("quizQuestion"))
    for (var ele of document.getElementsByClassName("quiz-button-latex")) {
        MQ.StaticMath(ele);
    }

},
```

Blazor page:

```
@page "/quiz"
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime;
@using Boolean_Algebra.Components.Quiz;
<h1 class="text-center main-web-width" id="title">Quiz</h1>

<QuizInterface manager="manager"/>


@code { 

public QuizManager manager;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    AssignManager();
}

private void AssignManager() {
    manager = new QuizManager();
    manager.onAnswer += (s,e)=> {
        AssignManager();

        this.StateHasChanged();

    };
}

protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("JsFunc.RenderQuizInterface");
}
}
```

Currently it renders the latex but it does not replace the old latex with the new question when my onAnswer event is called.
This works without the JsRuntime invoke but it will show raw latex on the page instead of the formatted latex. Is there a proper way to do this without breaking the rendertree?

Answer (score 1):

I received this comment on reddit

> The way to do it is to render output that Blazor won't try to keep
> track of. The trick is to render markup for your container rather than
> declaring it in razor.
>
> @((MarkupString) $"<div id=whatever>{ContentToTransform}</div>")
>
> See if that works

which solved the problem I described.